# Unable to install php in Macbook pro M1 with mac OS Ventura

Tags: php, apple-m1, macos-ventura

I'm not able to install php in my MacBook Pro M1 with Mac OS Ventura. I'm trying to install it using `brew`:

```bash
$> brew install php
...
dyld[72344]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib
  Referenced from: <87C1A268-34E4-396F-8BBC-D5591064E333> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gd/2.3.3_5/lib/libgd.3.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libavif/1.0.1/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libavif/1.0.1/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libavif/1.0.1/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
...
```

And when I try to run it:

```bash
$> php 
dyld[75056]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib
  Referenced from: <87C1A268-34E4-396F-8BBC-D5591064E333> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gd/2.3.3_5/lib/libgd.3.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libavif/1.0.1/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libavif/1.0.1/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libavif/1.0.1/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
[1]    75056 abort      php
```

Any idea?